# JIRA: Transfer project to another Atlassian account

Tags: bitbucket, jira, confluence

I have two Atlassian account

1. **ABC**.atlassian.net
2. **XYZ**.atlassian.net

And i have a jira project named **MUZ** on the the first account (**ABC**.atlassian.net) and i need to transfer this project to the second account (**XYZ**.atlassian.net).

The question is how to make this transfer for the jira project?, similarly for confluence and bitbucket project

Any help for the steps that should be followed, or the documentation that can help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*JIRA, Confluence and Bitbucket are different application in terms of its usage and these all applications have different approach to export the data from one instance to another.*

For **Jira**, You can export the issues to a .csv format spreadsheet and import the same csv to the another instance
You can refer to this link to export the csv here:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/how-to-export-to-csv/qaq-p/175115

Then

You can refer to this link to import the csv  https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/importing-data-from-csv-861253680.html

For **Confluence**, You can refer to instructions mentioned here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confcloud/import-a-confluence-space-724765531.html

For **Bitbucket**, At the moment, this feature is not available in Bitbucket Server and we have an open feature request here:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-4586

For sure you could use the REST APIs to retrieve and create the data.

You can always import the Git repository itself (including the entire history) by following the instructions on the Importing code from an existing project page.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html